# Fixed background attachment on a linear gradient causes lag on scroll

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

I have been trying to implement a linear gradient as my background, however, a persistent issue seems to appear when I use `background-attachment: fixed`. It seems that on mobile devices, when you attempt to scroll down the page quickly, the page will lag and the gradient will attempt to fill whitespace.

I've looked at multiple options that attempt to transform the background, but none have worked thus far.

[Issue on android](https://streamable.com/gv3e6n)

Here is how my body css looks like:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

CSS that references the background:

```
body, nav, #footer {
         background: linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(216, 100%, 17%, 1) 0%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 47%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 83%);
         background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(216, 100%, 17%, 1) 0%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 47%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 83%);
         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(216, 100%, 17%, 1) 0%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 47%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 83%);
         background-attachment: fixed;
     }
```

The HTML is formatted as follows:

```
<body>
    <nav>Navbar</nav>

    <div class="container">
        Page content
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>Developed</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The footer doesn't seem to have an effect on the situation at hand, but when I remove it, the whitespace narrowly reduces in size.

When I changed the background to a solid colour, the issue had resolved itself. So I am quite certain the issue relies on the linear background attempting to cover the space in a negative way.

Is there any setting that can combat the fixed attachment causing the scroll? I cannot remove it as of now as there will be a horrible change in colour.

Comment: The CSS code for your background is missing. Please provide all the relevant code to your issue so we can help you better.

Comment: @Ken Sorry, I've just added it now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your page because there's missing code/content. However, you should only apply the background to the "body" because "nav" and "footer" are inside the body.

In the example below, I only applied the background gradient to the body. Also, changed body height and removed the overflow for testing purposes only. I tested this on a mobile device using dev tool and works.

```css
body {
  //overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 1920px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(216, 100%, 17%, 1) 0%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 47%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 83%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(216, 100%, 17%, 1) 0%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 47%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 83%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(216, 100%, 17%, 1) 0%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 47%, hsla(206, 80%, 29%, 1) 83%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>Navbar</nav>

  <div class="container">
    Page content
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p>Developed</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The issue still exists unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully overcome my issue after playing around with some of the height settings with the html and body styles.

```
html {
    overflow: auto;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #051937, #001b49, #001b5a, #00196a, #0a1378);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Originally I had the height set to 100vh on the html style, when I removed that, it and added the `no-repeat` style to body, everything seemed to work brilliantly.